# How to get the variable value generated in JSR223 Preprocessor and use in HTTP header manager

Tags: groovy, jmeter, http-headers, jsr223, hmacsha1

I Wrote one script in JSR223 Pre processor in groovy and use the signature value in HTTP header manager.
But I am getting 1 in header response. I am using Property to fetch the value and store in Header manager. Still I can not get the correct value in output
Header response:

> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> TEST_REQUEST: test
>
> X-Hub-Signature: sha1=1
>
> Content-Length: 454
>
> Host: api.netomi.com
>
> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/13.0.1)

Below script I am using in JSR223

```
 {  
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(secretKeySpec);
    byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(b64encodedPayload.getBytes());
    encodedData = digest.encodeHex();
    log.info("HMAC SHA256 base64: " + encodedData);
    ${__setProperty(token, ${encodedData})}
    props.put("token", encodedData);
}
```

I am fetching the value in header manager as ${__P(token)}

[image: Saving the value in property file and generate the signature]

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Groovy code looks good (apart from using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty), you [should not be using JMeter Functions or Variables in the JSR223 Scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler))

   > When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.
2. Your [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) usage is also correct

The only reason I can think of is that you violate [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) somewhere somehow. Try putting both the JSR223 PreProcessor and the HTTP Header Manager **as the children** of the HTTP Request sampler you want to modify and it should resolve your issue:

[image]